# I want to apply the regular expression used in gitleaks in secretlint

Tags: regex, gitleaks

I am now trying to migrate from gitleaks to a tool called [secretlint](https://github.com/secretlint/secretlint).

Originally, there was a warning in the generic-api-key rule when executing gitleaks, but after moving to secretlint, the warning no longer occurs.

Specifically, I wrote the regular expression of [gitleaks.toml provided by gitleaks](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks/blob/master/config/gitleaks.toml#L630) in the secretlint configuration file .secretlintrc.json according to [the format of @secretlint-rule-pattern provided by secretlint](https://github.com/secretlint/secretlint/tree/master/packages/@secretlint/secretlint-rule-pattern#usage).

```
[[rules]]
id = "generic-api-key"
description = "Generic API Key"
regex = '''(?i)((key|api[^Version]|token|secret|password|auth)[a-z0-9_ .\-,]{0,25})(=|>|:=|\|\|:|<=|=>|:).{0,5}['\"]([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]{8,64})['\"]'''
entropy = 3.7
secretGroup = 4
keywords = [
    "key",
    "api",
    "token",
    "secret",
    "password",
    "auth",
]
```

to

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "@secretlint/secretlint-rule-pattern",
      "options": {
        "patterns": [
          {
            "name": "Generic API key",
            "pattern": "/(?i)((key|api[^Version]|token|secret|password|auth)[a-z0-9_ .\\-,]{0,25})(=|>|:=|\\|\\|:|<=|=>|:).{0,5}['\"]([0-9a-zA-Z\\-_=]{8,64})['\"]/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm thinking that perhaps I'm not migrating the regex correctly, but if anyone can tell me where I'm going wrong, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the the inline `(?i)` modifier is not supported by the JavaScript regex engine. You must use the normal `i` flag after the second regex delimiter (`/.../i`).

Also, the `api[^Version]` is a typical user error. If you meant to say `api` not followed with `Version`, you need `api(?!Version)`.

So you can use

```
"pattern": "/((key|api(?!Version)|token|secret|password|auth)[\\w .,-]{0,25})([=>:]|:=|\\|\\|:|<=|=>).{0,5}['\"]([\\w=-]{8,64})['\"]/i"
```

Note that I "shrunk" `[A-Za-z0-9_]` into a single `\w`, they are equivalent here. Note the `-` char does not need escaping when used at the end (or start) of a character class.